# Borel regular measure on a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, geometric-measure-theory

> Let $f(x,y)$ be a positive, differentiable function defined in the unit disc $D\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ and let
>
> $S=\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \mid x^2+y^2<1, z=f(x,y)\}$
>
> Given $A \subset S$, Borel subset of $S$, define $\pi (A):=\{(x,y)\in D \mid (x,y,f(x,y)) \in A\} \subset D$, and

$$m(A)=\int_{\pi(A)} \sqrt{f_x^2+f_y^2+1} \, dx \, dy$$

> Show that $m(\cdot)$ is Borel regular measure in $S$.

To show it is Borel measure, we have to show that every Borel set $A\subset S$ is $m(\cdot)$ measurable. To show it is $\it{regular}$, we have to show that for every set $A ⊆ S$ there exists a $m(\cdot)$ measurable set $E$ such that $A ⊆ E$ and $m(A) = m(E)$. If $A ⊆ E$, then, I have to show that

$$m(E)-m(A)=\int_{\pi(E) -\pi(A)} \sqrt{f_x^2+f_y^2+1} \, dx \, dy=0$$

Since $\sqrt{f_x^2+f_y^2+1}\subset \mathbb{L}_1(S,\mu)$, where $\mu(\cdot)$ is Lebesgue measure, the above equation means absolutely continuity which implies

$$\mu (\pi (E)-\pi (A))=0$$

Then, what does the above equation imply on? How I should continue?

Please leave me a comment if you know how I should proceed.

Comment: 1. Do you want $A \subseteq S$ in the first line after the highlighted box? 2. You have defined the (outer) measure only on Borel sets, and the regularity has to work for any set (including nonmeasurable), how do you define $m(A)$?

Comment: @SilviaGhinassi Thanks. Yes, A⊆S  and I fixed it. 2. I have to show it is regular for Borel sets. m(A) is defined in the forth line of the problem statement.

Comment: In the fourth line you defined $m$ for a Borel set. Do you want to define $m$ in the same way for any set? To prove regularity you need to prove what you say for **every** set $A$, as you say (if $A$ is already Borel, there's nothing to check).

Comment: @SilviaGhinassi I corrected the statement. (first line of my proof). May be I am confused. When the problem wants to to show it is Regular Borel, then why I should prove it is regular for any general set A?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_regular_measure

Comment: @SilviaGhinassi Thanks. I edited that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30615/discussion-between-susan-and-silvia-ghinassi).